# using case clause with join statement sql

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I have the following query:

```
select * from isg.tdbFutures f, isg.tdbOption e 
    where 
        f.contract = 306121 and
        e.underlier = f.entityID
```

Which will return this:

```
 entityID     lastTradeDate     expiration     firstTradeDate     contract     lastTradeDate     underlier     isPut     expiration     strike     entityID     optionMetricsID     expirationCycle    
 -----------  ----------------  -------------  -----------------  -----------  ----------------  ------------  --------  -------------  ---------  -----------  ------------------  ------------------ 
 311320       3/1/2018          3/1/2018       6/22/2017          306123       12/22/2017        311320        false     12/22/2017     100        368145       0                   monthly            
 311320       3/1/2018          3/1/2018       6/22/2017          306123       12/22/2017        311320        false     12/22/2017     106        368146       0                   monthly            
 311320       3/1/2018          3/1/2018       6/22/2017          306123       12/22/2017        311320        false     12/22/2017     120        368147       0                   monthly
```

I want to build a string to insert into another table, conditioned on the isPut column. This is my attempt:

```
select * from isg.tdbFutures f, isg.tdbOption e 
     where 
        f.contract = 306123 and
        e.underlier = f.entityID
     CASE isPut
        WHEN false THEN 'FI_US_M Call'
        WHEN true THEN 'FI_US_M Put'
     END
```

However, I get the following error:

```
>[Error] Script lines: 45-52 ------------------------
 SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'false' on line 6
 Msg: 102, Level: 15, State: 0
 Line: 0
```

The table I wat to insert in, where `category` is the string from my conditional and `entityID` is my `f.contract` value:

```
 category           entityID    
 -----------------  ----------- 
 US Equity          66281       
 US Fixed Income    66283       
 AUD                66359
```

Comment: The `case` expression belongs in the `select` clause, not the `from`clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it seems like even moving the `case` clause before the `where` results in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you seem to want is:

```
select f.*, o.*,
       (case when isPut then 'FI_US_M Put'
             else 'FI_US_M Call'
        end) as new_column
from isg.tdbFutures f join
     isg.tdbOption o 
     on o.underlier = f.entityID
where f.contract = 306123;
```

Notes:

- Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- As a best practice, you should list out all the columns in the `select`.
- Table aliases should be abbreviations for the table name, so I changed `e` to `o`.
- The `case` *expression* belongs in the `select`.
  -

Comment: As a followup, if I wanted to replace `FI_US_M` with a query, would it be possible? For example: `(select category from isg.tdbExternCategory where entityID = 306123)+' Put'`

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois . . . Yes, you can replace the value with a scalar subquery -- one that returns one column and zero or one rows.

Answer (score 0):

As @GordonLinoff points out, shouldn't it be like:

```
select 
    *,
    CASE isPut
       WHEN false THEN 'FI_US_M Call'
       WHEN true THEN 'FI_US_M Put'
    END as my_new_column
   from isg.tdbFutures f, isg.tdbOption e 
   where 
        f.contract = 306123 and
        e.underlier = f.entityID
```

Comment: I want to insert the result of `'FI_US_M Call'` or `'FI_US_M Put` into another table along with my `f.contract` value, what's the significance as the `as my_new_column`?

Comment: The new column is a "computed column". You can use it any way you like. For example for an insert. From your question is not clear where you want to insert that column: will it replace an existing column? will it be a new column?

Comment: My mistake, I updated the post to include what my desired insert is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

select * from isg.tdbFutures f, isg.tdbOption e ,
 CASE
        WHEN isPut = false THEN 'FI_US_M Call'
       else  'FI_US_M Put' end
     where 
        f.contract = 306123 and
        e.underlier = f.entityID

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert into another table, shouldn't it be something like this then?

```
insert new_column_from_case = CASE isPut WHEN false THEN 'FI_US_M Call'
                                         WHEN true THEN 'FI_US_M Put'
                                         END
       new_f_contract = f.contract
  into another_table
  from isg.tdbFutures f, isg.tdbOption e 
 where f.contract = 306123 
   and e.underlier = f.entityID
```